# How to capture the window where flutter widget's area is located

Tags: flutter, winapi, desktop, screen-capture

hi guys im making my own flutter desktop program
but when trying to make a fucntion that capturing the window where flutter widget's area is located i have troubled..

- first, i tried to transparent the program's background and capture the widget(by using flutter_acrylic and RenderRepaintBoundary).[transparent image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clCee.png)
- when i caputred widget the image wasnt include transparent window.. but only tranparent color was. because caputre algorithm see only the widget. im blocked in this problem.[widget capture image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofnys.png)

anyone who have idea for this problem  please give me wisdom...
+Now I tying to get information about the win32 API. Any ideas on win32 capture API would be much appreciated.

- i did!! anyone want to know see these links https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image + https://pub.dev/packages/win32

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sReyb.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

About win32 capture API, you can use GDI `BitBlt` function. Here is a MSDN sample [Capturing an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image).

You need to find the flutter desktop program window's handle with [FindWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa),  then get the rect range, and  capture the window from DC.

```
HDC hWndDC = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
RECT capture_rect{ 0,0,0,0 }; 
RECT wnd_rect; 
RECT real_rect; 

GetWindowRect(hwnd, &wnd_rect);
DwmGetWindowAttribute(hwnd, DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE::DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, &real_rect, sizeof(RECT));

int offset_left = real_rect.left - wnd_rect.left;
int offset_top = real_rect.top - wnd_rect.top;
capture_rect = RECT{ offset_left,offset_top,real_rect.right - real_rect.left + offset_left,real_rect.bottom - real_rect.top + offset_top };    

//capture_rect ?? wnd_rect (You can calculate the capture_rect based on the size of your window)

int width = capture_rect.right - capture_rect.left;
int height = capture_rect.bottom - capture_rect.top;  

HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hWndDC);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hWndDC, width, height);
SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);

BitmapPtr bitmap;

bool ok = BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, width, height, hWndDC, capture_rect.left, capture_rect.top, SRCCOPY);

DeleteDC(hWndDC);
DeleteDC(hMemDC);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
```

Comment: thx for help :) . are u know how to improve resolution of output?? when i capture program and capture again the output image's resolution getting bad.

Comment: Could you show your output image?